How to Remove Menu Items in Wordpress
I am trying to remove some menu items for my ShopManager to simplify her admin portal and also restrict access to certain features.
I managed to remove some items from the Woocommerce menu.
However, for some reason I am unable to remove items from the Bookings menu.
I would like to remove the following menu items: resources, add product, and settings.
Here is the like i used to remove the resources menu item but it isnt working:
function customize_shop_manager_dashboard_and_menus() {
    //WORKING FINE
    // Remove specific WooCommerce sub-menu items from WOOCOMMERCE DROP DOWN
    remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-admin&path=/customers'); // Customers
    remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-admin&path=/extensions'); // Extensions
    remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-settings'); // Settings
    remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-status'); // Status
    remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'wc-extensions'); // Extensions

    // NOT WORKING
    remove_submenu_page('wc_bookings', 'edit.php?post_type=bookable_resource'); 
}

// Hook the function into the appropriate actions
add_action('admin_menu', 'customize_shop_manager_dashboard_and_menus', 110);

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

remove_submenu_page() is looking for the slug and then the menu path. Woocommerce slugs are admin.php or edit.php - the not working one for you should just be remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'post_type=bookable_resource');

@disinfor thank you for your comment. Here is the slug as it appears in the browser: www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=bookable_resource. Unfortunately your code didnt work.

You can determine the correct menu/submemu slug combination by running the code: print_r($GLOBALS['submenu'], true);  as described in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/#comment-3114

@KalenGi Hello, that worked perfectly. Thank you very much.
